# How to debug embedded application startup on Motorola FX7500

Tags: java, rfid, motorola, motorola-emdk

We have an application running on Motorola FX7500 RFID reader. Everything works fine except auto-start. Looks like start_appname.sh is executed but application doesn't even start. Is there any way to debug application startup? Or to find fail reason in log files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autostart function is not working on firmware version 1.2.9
You should update to firmware version 1.2.10 (this is not yet available on the www.motorolasolutions.com website)
You should be able to get the new firmware from the Motorola helpdesk.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Will try to get new firmware.

Answer (score 0):

1.2.10 is available on request to Moto helpdesk. It will not be postet, the fix will be incorporated into next official image release.

Comment: I've emailed a request for the new firmware to Moto helpdesk about one month ago and still haven't received anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'am working with Motorola RFID FX7400 and works for me.
Install your application on `\\Application.`

Use Active Sync Remote Display to view the screen of the reader.

On your computer copy and paste into notepad and save has *.reg

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\StartUp\Programs\Prog19]
    "Name"="\\Application\\MyFolder\\MyApp.exe"
    "Command"=""
    "Continue"=dword:1
    "ColdBootOnly"=dword:0
```

Put the file on the reader \Application and run it.

I'am from Mexico, sorry for my english.